# Captive portal not redirecting

Tags: coovachilli

Basically I have been trying to setup coovachilli with radius/mysql authentication to act as a captive portal,on my virtual machine.
When a client connect to chillispot, his IP is "10.1.0.X" so he can't communicate with box (x.x.x.x) and can't go on internet.
So to be sure,I debug coova-chilli server running process.In there ,redirection process are not work.
I have now spent all week till the early hours of the morning trying to get this working but not redirection to from coova server to client.

If anybody knows it, please help me out.

Comment: You might want to add to the question (editing it) what you have tried so far. Without this information, little help can be given to you.

Comment: I have built several routers with CoovaChilli and the redirection works perfect. Could you show which is your configuration ? And how are you redirecting within the HTML ? is local or WAN redirection ?

Comment: Thank you.I found my problem the last day .It is not redirection problem.I have change UAMALLOW value. My server is run well.

Comment: @kaykay What is UAMALLOW for ?